# Executar Shell Script verificando a arquitetura do sistema 32bit ou 64bit

Tags: shell-script

Como posso fazer um script que verifique a arquitetura do sistema e assim ele executaria os comandos para a arquitetura adequada, por exemplo:

```
if 32bit; then

comandos para 32 bits

else

comandos para 64 bits
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encontrei uma resposta que detecta diferentes tipos de arquiteturas no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7813672/1518921), note que cada `case` faz uma checagem:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST_ARCH=$(uname -m)

case "$HOST_ARCH" in
    x86)     HOST_ARCH="x86"          ;;
    i?86)    HOST_ARCH="x86"          ;;
    ia64)    HOST_ARCH="ia64"         ;;
    amd64)   HOST_ARCH="amd64"        ;;
    x86_64)  HOST_ARCH="x86_64"       ;;
    sparc64) HOST_ARCH="sparc64"      ;;
    * )      HOST_ARCH="desconhecido" ;;
esac

echo
echo "A arquitetura do seu sistema é: $HOST_ARCH"
echo
```

Exemplo no IDEONE: https://ideone.com/iaBg8b

Ou pode até simplificar para algo como:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST_ARCH=$(uname -m)

case "$HOST_ARCH" in
    x86)     HOST_ARCH="32"           ;;
    i?86)    HOST_ARCH="32"           ;;
    ia64)    HOST_ARCH="64"           ;;
    amd64)   HOST_ARCH="64"           ;;
    x86_64)  HOST_ARCH="64"           ;;
    sparc64) HOST_ARCH="64"           ;;
    * )      HOST_ARCH="desconhecido" ;;
esac

if [ $HOST_ARCH = "64" ]; then
   # comandos para 64
elif [ $HOST_ARCH = "32" ]; then
   # comandos para 32
else
   echo "Sistema não suportado";
fi
```

Exemplo no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/NeKUxT)

---

A resposta do [Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289763/3635) parece boa, mas o `else` não garante que seja 64-bit, creio que o melhor seja salvar em uma variavel e usar um `elif`, por exemplo:

```
HOST_ARCH=$(file /bin/bash | cut -d' ' -f3);

if [ $HOST_ARCH = "32-bit" ]; then

   # comandos para 32 bits

elif [ $HOST_ARCH = "64-bit" ]; then

   # comandos para 64 bits

else
   echo "Sistema não suportado";
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(uname -m) = "x86_64" ]; then
    echo "x64"
else
    echo "x86"
fi
```

Comment: Tbm funciona, Obrigado!

Comment: O `else` não garante que a arquitetura seja x86, supondo que eventualmente este script possa ser executado em uma arquitetura totalmente diferente e incomum.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pode dar alguns exemplos de os/arch? Um elseif ao invés de else então?

Comment: @TomMelo isso mesmo, um `elif` para o x86 (i686, i586, i486 e i386) e no `else` você colocaria um `echo "desconhecido";`

Comment: Pensando bem, talvez o uname -m não seja uma boa opção...

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo a verificação da variável de sistema LONG_BIT:

```
if [ $(getconf LONG_BIT) = 64 ]; then
  echo "64bits";
elif [ $(getconf LONG_BIT) = 32  ]; then
  echo "32bits";
else 
  echo "another";
fi
```

Outra opção seria a verificação uname -m que retorna:

- x64, ia64, amd64 e x86_64 seria 64 bits;
- i686, i586, i486 e i386, seriam 32 bits;